# In Vim, how can I search for the contents of a register?

Tags: vim

Say I've yanked the text "foo" into register `x`. How can I search my file for the contents of that register?

I know that I can type `/` to search, then `Control+R` followed by `x` to paste the contents of that register, leaving me with `/foo`. But I'm trying to use the name of the register instead.

For example, I tried `/@a`, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

That's basically the easiest way to do it.  If you want to script it, you could use something like this:

```
:execute '/' . @x
```

Comment: Any way to do a replace on it ?

Comment: @Stephane Something like: `:execute '%s/' . @x . '/foo/g'`